# Nodejs - Mysql and nulls

Tags: mysql, node.js, null

I've been using the following [mysql client](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) in node. I have noticed for some querys(mostly nulls) I get the following string appearing(**"\u0001"**) - where I would expect `NaN`(if I was using mysql-native) or `null`.

I have also noticed it where I use booleans in my data - before anybody points out I know this is mysql so I use bits to replicate boolean data. Still I get the crazy string above being returned.

If someone could explain what this is and possibly how to get around it I would be grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `\u0001` notation is an escape sequence indicating a [Unicode character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#C0_Controls_and_Basic_Latin).